# Is there any way to get response header details in exposed SOAP webservice Apex class method?

Tags: apex, integration, webservices, soap, header

Please enlighten me\correct me on following point:

**Is there any way to get response header details in exposed SOAP webservice Apex class method?**

Like for expamle:

1. For visualforce page, we can access response headers as : `ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders()`
2. For REST webservice class, we can accsess response headers with: 
   `getHeader method of RestContext.response`

It will be very helpful, if you could provide any sample code example

Answer (score 2):

Yes using `inputHttpHeaders_x and outputHttpHeaders_x` we can get and set the Header attribute in SOAP WSDL. Using them we can easily get cookies and other custom header.

```
docSample.DocSamplePort stub = new docSample.DocSamplePort();
stub.outputHttpHeaders_x = new Map<String, String>();
String input = 'This is the input string';
String output = stub.EchoString(input);

//Getting cookie header
String cookie = stub.outputHttpHeaders_x.get('Set-Cookie');

//Getting custom header
String myHeader = stub.outputHttpHeaders_x.get('My-Header');
```

[Apex Web Services and Callouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts)

Comment: Hi  Tushar, Thanks for Help! I tried same but i am not able access such parameters [inputHttpHeaders_x and outputHttpHeaders_x]. It will be great if you could provide any sample code example.

Comment: @Tushar I guess, this will help when you consume the WSDL, not while exposing the webservice. "This section shows an example of an **WSDL2Apex generated Apex method** that invokes an Amazon Web Service."

Comment: @YsrShkWe can get response as well. In the link there are two approach to get and set the headers.

Comment: @TusharSharma - Yes. But AFAIk stub mostly generated by Wsdl2Apex parser. If possible, could you pls redirect  on any sample webservice(not the consuming class, which is generated by parser), I would be delighted.